# why is gm (GraphicsMagick) not resizing my file?

Tags: node.js, graphicsmagick

According to a tutorial I'm working on, the code below tells `gm` to resize the image **in-place**.

It isn't doing it. It spits out the identical image file.

```
newForm.on('end', function() {
            fs.rename(tmpFile, nfile, function() {
                // resize image and upload to S3 bucket

                // I fs.read(nfile) here, log the buffer contents, and...                    

                gm(nfile).resize(300).write(nfile, function(err) {

                    // I fs.read(nfile) again, and the buffer contents
                    // are identical.
                    // The file has not been resized

                    // upload to S3, etc
                    // the unresized image is incorrectly uploaded to S3
                })
            })
        })
```

Is my `.write` wrong?

I'm getting this error in the console

```
(node) Buffer.write(string, encoding, offset, length) is deprecated. Use write(string[, offset[, length]][, encoding]) instead.
```

but it doesn't give me any clues what to change...

Comment: What happens when you try saving it to a different location instead of overwriting it?

Comment: doing that now... stand by

Comment: not going well...  [Error: Could not execute GraphicsMagick/ImageMagick: gm "convert" "/var/folders/yq/mh22dd953zz37c2g_56rz6jh0000gn/T/fiiinwfscahxalq1444765355379.jpg" "-resize" "300x" "/Users/davidwilbanks/Documents/resized.jpg" this most likely means the gm/convert binaries can't be found]           whereas the code posted above doesn't throw any errors at all...

Comment: Judging by that error message, it seems like it's an error with your installation of gm.  Have you followed the instructions here https://github.com/aheckmann/gm ?

Comment: of all the... skipped that step... and thanks!